# center on resize too

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, center

This works:

```
$.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position", "absolute");
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this
};
$('#container').center();
```

.. but the element stays in the same position if the window is resized, how do I center it with the resize too?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to execute that code in the `window` *resize* event. But, if the browser is resized this event fires huge! So it's in general a good idea to create a little "balancer".

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    var that = this;        

    if(!('balancer' in that) ) {
        that.balancer = setTimeout(function() {
            $('#container').center();
            delete that.balancer;
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

This will absorb the many events that are fired when resizing the browser window. In fact, it only calls the `.center()` at a maximum of 200ms. You probably should even increase that value and cache the node reference to the `#container` element.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**::

giving percentage to `top` and `left` can put at center. but this bad ... really really bad.

```
    $.fn.center = function () {
        $(this).css({'position': 'absolute',
                     'top': '40%',
                     'left': '40%'
                    });
    };

    $(function (){
        $('#container').center();
    })
```

On [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bzAmL/1/).