# jQuery | Center Object On Window Resize

Tags: jquery, resize

With the following function I center an object in the window if the user chooses so :

```
var showObj = function(obj) {

    setTimeout(function () {
        if(opts.centerObj == true) {
            var cssProps = {
                'position' :'absolute',
                'top' : (($(window).height() - $(obj).outerHeight()) / 2)+'px',
                'left' : (($(window).width() - $(obj).outerWidth()) / 2)+'px'
            }
            obj.css(cssProps).fadeIn('slow');
        }
            else {
                obj.fadeIn('slow');
            }
    }, 1500);

}
```

But I want to tweak this function or make another one which would center the object if the window resizes.

I've seen I can use this :

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   obj.css(cssProps);
});
```

But I think I'm wrong,because nothing happens when I resize the window.

So could someone show me how to create that function that does what I need or tweak the current function so it does that ?

Comment: This has been asked a bajillion times before...

Comment: possible duplicate of [center on resize too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634444/center-on-resize-too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on where you are calling `cssProps`. Since it's inside a private function it's not accessible unless you tell it to be. I think the easiest way to do what you want is to pull out the bit of code that creates the JS object and put it into it's own function.

```
var showObj = function(obj) {

    setTimeout(function () {
        if(opts.centerObj == true) {
            var cssProps = getProps(obj);
            obj.css(cssProps).fadeIn('slow');
        }
        else {
            obj.fadeIn('slow');
        }
    }, 1500);

}

var getProps = function(obj) {

    return {
        'position' :'absolute',
        'top' : (($(window).height() - $(obj).outerHeight()) / 2)+'px',
        'left' : (($(window).width() - $(obj).outerWidth()) / 2)+'px'
    }
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    var cssProps = getProps(obj);
    obj.css(cssProps);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked and deleted before and [here is my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658373/561731)<sup><sub><sup>(10K only)</sup></sub></sup>

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {

    var $self = $(this), _self = this;
    var window_resize = function(){
        var window_obj = $(window);
        $self.css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": (( window_obj.height() - _self.outerHeight()) / 2),
            "left": (( window_obj.width() - _self.outerWidth()) / 2)
        });
    }
    $self.bind('centerit', window_resize).trigger('centerit');
    $(window).bind('resize', function(){
        $self.trigger('centerit');
    });
    return _self;

}


$('div').center();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/JeBHJ/

Comment: Your link returns a Page Not Found.

Comment: @Seth it is a 10k deleted question

Comment: I know, but I'm not looking for another plugin, I have some other center plugins. I want to do this with a simple function , because I will use it inside a plugin.

Comment: @Roland what **are** you looking for?

Comment: @Neal, what @Seth wrote is what I need. But you plugin is good as well, for instance I'm using `$(window).bind('resize', function(){ ... });` instead of `$(window).resize()` because it's more appropriate for my plugin.

Comment: @Roland one thing to note also in @Neal's code is caching the selector. Rather than writing `$(window)` and `$(obj)` twice, assign those two variables to speed up your code.

Comment: I already took that piece of code in consideration @Seth, I'm using this method for `$(this)` as well in my plugin. Thank you :)